# Bitmap to String

Tags: java

Есть переменные:

`public Bitmap c=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.c);`

и
               `public String d;`

Каким образом можно присвоить переменной d имя переменной с?

ЗЫ Проблема в том, что переменных 'с' много. Чтоб каждый раз не делать d=c1..d=cn. Возможно с помощью Fields. С ним я пока не разобрался

Comment: String d = "c";

Comment: Проблема в том, что переменных 'с' много. Чтоб каждый раз не делать d=c1..d=cn. Возможно с помощью Fields. С ним я пока не разобрался.

Comment: Если `c` много, то налицо плохой выбор типов в приложении и нужно подобрать что-то более подходящее, скажем, массив.

Comment: Не стал париться и нагородил кучу строк, как предлагал Эникейщик. Это не "правильно" - зато просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью рефлексии вы можете получить массив полей класса и получить их имена:

```
Field[] fields = [Ваш объект].getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f : fields) {
           if(f.getAnnotatedType().getType().equals(Bitmap.class)) d = f.getName();

        }
```